Construction of a parity operator to apply on a lattice system
I am confused with the correct general form of the parity operator to apply it on a lattice system. I am working with the Bose hubbard model of n-sites 1D and total number of particles is fixed.
I want to create a phase difference \theta between the left and the right sides (two sites for left region and two sites for right region).
For the case of n-sites hubbard model and for pi-phase difference, there is this formula for Parity = (-1)^{number operator on left-side tensor product identity operator on right side} to apply on the entire two-site hubbard model.
How do I construct it's matrix for parity operator with a general phase difference of \theta? Can somebody please explain an efficient method step by step? For example, for two sites, do I need to explicity add a phase only to the left side state (stored in the form of a tuple) using the above formula? And then take the superposition of all the basis states?
Any assistance on this will be greatly appreciated. Thanks
